# facebook api access token: session has expired

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

Below is the code:

```
token=..
graph=facebook.GraphAPI(token)
data = graph.request('/search?q=baby&type=user')
```

Actually I just run the code successfully few hours before, now it says"

> facebook.GraphAPIError: Error validating access token: Session has
>   expired on Tuesday, 17-Oct-17 21:00:00 PDT. The current time is
>   Wednesday, 18-Oct-17 01:06:39 PDT

Anyone occur this error?

Comment: what´s unclear about the error? user tokens are valid for 2 hours, extended user tokens are valid for 60 days. more info: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: or: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: @luschn ah..I SEE...

Comment: added the comment as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User Tokens are valid for 2 hours, Extended User Tokens are valid for 60 days. After that time, you have to get a new Token. There is no way to auto-generate a new one, user interaction is neccessary.

More info:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: What does it mean "user interaction is neccessary."? Do we need to generate a new token after every 60 days?

Comment: yes, but you cannot just generate it automatically without user interaction. if the user did not use your app in 60 days, there is no way to generate a new token.

Comment: Not sure what this user interaction is? I post to facebook page regularly from my web backend. I just regenerated the access token from FB developer tool. Seems to work?

Comment: yes, that would be user interactin, you regenerate the token from the dev tool instead auf auto-generating something without your input ;)